# InvalidProtocolBufferException: on Impala connecting to Hadoop 2.x.x

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, impala

I have installed CDH Hadoop hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.3.2 and impala 2.1 from http://archive.cloudera.com/impala/ubuntu/precise/amd64/impala/pool/contrib/i/impala/ in a ubuntu 12.04 64 bit version .

I configured both hadoop and impala.

I want to use impala to query csv on hdfs directly .

My hadoop along with hdfs is perfectly up and running .

But whenever I am trying to make Impala up , I  am  getting the below error.

**Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Message missing required fields: callId, status; Host Details : local host is: "localhost/127.0.0.1"; destination host is: "localhost":54310;**

I understand that HADOOP 2 is using protobuf version 2.5 but impala that I  have installed is using protobuf version 2.4 .

Please help me how sort out this problem .

How to install a Hadoop 2.x version working with Impala ???

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue . The problem was due to protobuf version mismatch.

The Impala is using HDFS directly without taking the help of the mapreduce framework . So in order to talk with each other they need to use the common protobuf version , because the message format is different for different protobuf version .

> Solution:-
>
> 1. Compile both impala and hadoop using same protobuf version .
>      Or
> 2. Use a Hadoop/Hive/Impala for the same CDH version .

http://archive.cloudera.com/impala/

http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/